# Why does this CMake project not set the appropriate MSVC runtime?

Tags: cmake, msvcrt, libmysql

I'm trying to understand why the libmysql CMake project configured with /MD and /MDd flags does not generate the appropriate Visual Studio 10 project files.  The appropriate `CMAKE_` macros have been configured, as shown:

[image: macros]

Yet the generated projects are still showing unexpected Runtime Library settings:

[image]

Is the CMake GUI for some reason unreliable, or is it possible that another option is overriding the CRT settings?

Comment: Do all of your dependencies (like libmysql since its tagged) use /MTd?

Comment: @drescherjm please note that libmysql *is* the project I'm attempting to generate using cmake.  I've also updated question with further investigations.

Comment: The GUI does not pick up on these because the GUI only reads and writes the values to and from the cache not the result of the generate.

Comment: It's very misleading, though.  The values displayed are not ever used when generating the project files.  A user's changes would never take effect.  Why not just `FORCE` these flags so that at least the user is aware of the actual values being used to generate the project files?

Comment: @jwalk That is a very good question, but one for the authors of `libmysql` CMake support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the cmake project for libmysql has an OS-specific cmake file for Windows which forces static runtimes to be used when generating the Visual Studio solution:

```
 75   # Force static runtime libraries
 83   FOREACH(flag
 84    CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
 85    CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT
 86    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
 87    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT)
 88    STRING(REPLACE "/MD"  "/MT" "${flag}" "${${flag}}")
 89    SET("${flag}" "${${flag}} /EHsc")
 98   ENDFOREACH()
```